# Why is ::feof() different from ::_eof(::fileno())?

Tags: c++, file-io, stream, filestream

**DISCLAIMER:  Don't use `::feof()` as your loop condition.**  For example, see the answer to:  [file reading: feof() for binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181081/file-reading-feof-for-binary-files)

However, I have "real" code that demonstrates a problem that does not use `::feof()` as my loop condition, but LOGICALLY, this is the easiest way to demonstrate the problem.

Consider the following:  We iterate a character stream one-at-a-time:

```
FILE* my_file;
// ...open "my_file" for reading...

int c;
while(0 == ::feof(my_file))
{ // We are not at EOF
  c = ::getc(my_file);
  // ...process "c"
}
```

**The above code works as expected:**  The file is processed one-char-at-a-time, and upon `EOF`, we drop out.

HOWEVER, **the following has unexpected behavior**:

```
FILE* my_file;
// ...open "my_file" for reading...

int c;
while(0 == ::_eof(::fileno(my_file)))
{ // We are not at EOF
  c = ::getc(my_file);
  // ...process "c"
}
```

I would have expected them to perform the same.  `::fileno()` properly returns the (integer) file descriptor every time.  However, the test `::_eof(::fileno(my_file))` works *exactly once*, and then returns `1` (indicating an `EOF`) on the second attempt.

I do not understand this.

I suppose it is conceivable that `::feof()` is "buffered" (so it works correctly) while `::_eof()` is "un-buffered" and thinks the whole file is "read-in" already (because the whole file would have fit into the first block read in from disk).  However, that can't possibly be true given the purpose of those functions.  So, I'm really at a loss.

What's going on?

(Files are opened as "text", are ASCII text files with about a dozen lines, MSVS2008, Win7/64.)

Comment: You should check return value of getc() to check for EOF also.
 if(c!=EOF)  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getc/

Comment: Your code is still incorrect. You have to check for EOF *after* reading but *before* processing. You won't see the end-of-file until you've run into it.

Comment: Agree with both comments above (@Rajendran && @Kerrek). However, those issues are not present in my use case: The file is not empty, and has multiple lines; `feof()` works correctly; `_eof(fileno())` fails (returns `1`) after the first character is read. So, those legitimate complaints about my "incorrect condition" don't apply to this case. (That's why I lead with a disclaimer.)

Comment: In fact it DOES apply in your case. What Rajendran and Kerrek are saying is a separate issue from the one you linked to, and does not only apply to empty files. feof does not return 1 after you read the last byte of the file, it returns 1 after you try to read PAST the end of the file. So you are processing an EOF as a character in your loop.

Comment: @Gerald, I don't see/understand it:  After exactly one `getc()` on a file with many lines, `_eof()` returns `1`.  It returns `0` before the first read, and the first read (correctly) returns a char (and is not at `EOF`). I'm still trying to understand your answer below, and what the purpose is for `_eof()` if it always returns `1` even when you didn't read anything (after the first char).

Comment: I updated my answer. In short, _eof does not work with file streams, it works with file descriptors, which are not analogous to file streams.

Comment: @charley, the code that implements `getc` is entitled to read as much of the file as it pleases. If it wants, it it allowed to read all of the file and to put the file descriptor into an EOF-state. Now, of course, it only returns 1 character. The rest of the string is buffered in the *stream*. And the *stream*'s `feof()` is not yet true.

Comment: Although, maybe your first priority should be to understand that your first block of code is wrong; the code that you think "The above code works as expected: ". It will loop around exactly once too often. Once you allow yourself to fully understand why everyone are telling you that it is wrong, that might help you to be a little more careful with other issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I suppose it is conceivable that ::feof() is "buffered" (so it works
>   correctly) while ::_eof() is "un-buffered" and thinks the whole file
>   is "read-in" already (because the whole file would have fit into the
>   first block read in from disk). However, that can't possibly be true
>   given the purpose of those functions. So, I'm really at a loss.

I don't know why you would think it "can't possibly be true given the purpose of those functions." The 2 functions are meant to operate on files that are opened and operated on  in different ways, so they are not compatible.

In fact, that is exactly what is happening. Try this:

```
FILE* my_file;
// ...open "my_file" for reading...

int c;
while(0 == ::_eof(::fileno(my_file)))
{ // We are not at EOF
  c = ::getc(my_file);

  long offset1 = ftell(my_file);
  long offset2 = _tell(fileno(my_file));

  if (offset1 != offset2)
  {
     //here you will see that the file pointers are different
     //which means that _eof and feof will fire true under different conditions
  }
  // ...process "c"
}
```

I will try to elaborate a bit based on your comment.

When you call fopen, you are getting back a pointer to a file **stream**. The underlying stream object keeps it's own file pointer which is separate from the *actual* file pointer associated with the underlying file descriptor.

When you call _eof you are asking if you have reached the end of the actual file. When you call feof, you are asking if you have reached the end of the file **stream**. Since file streams are usually buffered, the end of the file is reached before the end of the stream.

> I'm still trying to understand your answer below, and what the purpose
>   is for _eof() if it always returns 1 even when you didn't read
>   anything (after the first char).

To answer this question, the purpose of _eof is to determine if you have reached the end of the file when using _open and _read to work directly with file descriptors, not when you use fopen and fread or getc to work with file streams.

Comment: It took me some time to conclude/understand that @Gerald is correct in his answer.  Thanks, @Gerald!