# Can someone explain the segmentation fault in this?

Tags: c

I have written a piece of code which reads a text file foo.txt which is of format:

```
1
2
3
4
```

It stores the last number and increments it and writes it back. This is the part where I'm storing the last number and the next part of the code will be writing the number to the file. The file is called by `./readfile 100 foo.txt`, where 100 is the number of times it has to increment the last number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char ch[100];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int count = atoi(argv[1]);

    while (count != 0) {
        fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
        while (fp) {
            ch[i] = fgetc(fp);
            i++;
            j = i;
            printf("%d", j);    
        }
        fclose(fp);
        count--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(fp)` will always be true (assuming the call to `fopen` succeeds).

Comment: in your while loop, add `if (feof(fp)) break;`

Comment: @NickWhite: [Don't use `feof`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3181093/364696). File operations should generally use what Python calls the EAFP pattern (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than seek Permission); do what you want to do, and handle the error.

Comment: What do you suggest I do instead of `feof()`?

Comment: @KshitijBantupalli: I added it to my answer; if you don't see it, refresh the page.

Comment: @KshitijBantupalli: instead of `while(fp)`, use `int c; while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
while (fp)
```

A `FILE*` is, to a boolean test, just another pointer. So as long as it opened successfully, that test always passes. You keep reading character at a time, storing into successive elements of the array, until you overflow, and eventually end up writing into unallocated memory entirely (or coincidentally stomping something important and causing a crash some other way).

You really want something like:

```
    // Must read into int; EOF itself is not a char value
    int inchar;
    // Read and test for EOF
    while((inchar = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        ch[i] = inchar;  // Store
        i++;
        printf("%d", inchar); // Print raw value returned by fgetc
    }
```

Comment: I just added a `while(1)` loop and used `if(feof(fp))     break;`.

Comment: @KshitijBantupalli: As I noted in the comments on the question, [don't use `feof`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3181093/364696); it only tells you you've reached the end of the file after you've read garbage. `fgetc` itself will both read a character and tell you if it has reached the end of the file, so `feof` is just wasting cycles checking flags when `fgetc` has already told you what's going on.

Comment: @KshitijBantupalli: To be clear, the `while` loop I provided as an example is basically _the_ canonical approach to reading a file one character at a time; most docs (say, [cppreference.com's `fgetc` docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc)) use the exact same pattern.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger

Comment: @KshitijBantupalli: the best advice you got here is: **never ever use feof()**

Answer (score 1):

After you fix "while (fp)" issue. You still has problem with ch[i]. With your code, "i" will be increased to 400. So segmentation fault occurs.

```
    while(fp)
    {
        ch[i] = fgetc(fp);
        i++;
        j = i;
        printf("%d", j);    
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it will be increased to 400?

Comment: You has two loops in your code. "while(count!=0)" is 100 times. "while(fp)" is expected to 4 times. 100 x 4 = 400.